# Catching boto3 ClientError subclass

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

With code like the snippet below, we can catch AWS exceptions:

```
from aws_utils import make_session

session = make_session()
cf = session.resource("iam")
role = cf.Role("foo")
try:
    role.load()
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
    raise e
```

The returned error is of type `botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException`. However, when I try to import this exception, I get this:

```
>>> import botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named NoSuchEntityException
```

The best method I could find of catching this specific error is:

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
session = make_session()
cf = session.resource("iam")
role = cf.Role("foo")
try:
    role.load()
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "NoSuchEntity":
        # ignore the target exception
        pass
    else:
        # this is not the exception we are looking for
        raise e
```

But this seems very "hackish". Is there a way to directly import and catch specific subclasses of `ClientError` in boto3?

EDIT: Note that if you catch errors in the second way and print the type, it will be `ClientError`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you're using the [client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#client) you can catch the exceptions like this:

```
import boto3

def exists(role_name):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    try:
        client.get_role(RoleName='foo')
        return True
    except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
        return False
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're using the [resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#service-resource) you can catch the exceptions like this:

```
cf = session.resource("iam")
role = cf.Role("foo")
try:
    role.load()
except cf.meta.client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
    # ignore the target exception
    pass
```

This combines the earlier answer with the simple trick of using `.meta.client` to get from the higher-level resource to the lower-level client (source: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html#creating-clients).

Comment: could someone explain, how this is caught by except? How does a different class from errorfactory map to this one?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Does this solution fail to work for you? Or are you just interested in _how_ it works?

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>   try:
>       something 
>  except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
>       something
> ```

This worked for me

Comment: This is a duplicate of the first and accepted answer. Or am I missing something?