# Check if IAM user exists in an AWS account programmatically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to check if an IAM  user exists in an AWS account programmatically.
Is this possible ?

Use Case: Automation Script, where user enters the AWS account to be used as input. After this point, I want to verify if a specific IAM user exists in that account.

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible. But rather than give you the code to do it, I'm going to ask you three questions: (1) are you familiar with the `boto3` module? (2) if yes, are you able to create an `iam` client? (3) if yes, can you find the method that would let you "list users"?

Comment: 1) Yup! meant to add using boto3 2)&3) Thanks! will look into this

Comment: Are you saying that your user will provide their IAM user name to your automation script? How will your automation actually use that information when the automation runs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#user) to check for IAM users:

```
import boto3
iam = boto3.resource('iam')
user = iam.User('name')
user.load()
```

This will throw a `NoSuchEntityException` exception if the user doesn't exist.

If successful loaded you'll be able to access the users attributes, e.g. `user.arn`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling across this, I needed to check if a user existed for a client instance, not a resource instance. While @yvesonline's answer works, it wasn't quite what I needed, so here is one for clients:

Based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44346062/3155240).

```
import boto3

def exists(user_name):
    client = boto3.client('iam')
    try:
        client.get_user(UserName=user_name)
        return True
    except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
        return False
```

I don't know why the user decided to use `get_role` instead of `get_user`, but whatever.